# Typhoon: how to inject class instead of instance

Tags: swift, unit-testing, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have a third-party library which is written in Swift. The library provides a class that has some class methods in it. Using Typhoon, I want to inject the class into one of my classes so that, under unit testing, I could inject a mock class that provides fake class methods. I'm new to Typhoon and I went though the documentation, but haven't figured out how to do it. Is this even doable with Typhoon?

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but you could also create a simple thin wrapper of your 3rd party class(with instance methods instead of class ones) and inject it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the User Guide the section on Injecting Configuration shows how to inject primitives, scalar values and so forth.

**To inject a class:**

```
[initializer injectParameterWith:[SomeClass class]];
```

This also applies to property injection and method injection.

**To inject a selector:**

```
[initializer injectParameterWith:NSValueFromPrimitive(@selector(selectorValue))];
```

**Typhoon rules:**

- References to other definitions are resolved to the built instance.
- Simple objects, primitives and scalar values are injected as-is (scalar values and primitives must be wrapped).
- Collections (NSArray, NSSet, etc) that contain references to other definitions have those references resolved to the built instance. Any other values pass through as is.

There is also [Typhoon Config](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#typhoon-config), which allows storing configuration, simple objects and so forth in an external plist, json or properties file.